# when making an image float other block elements go behind it?

Tags: html, css

So basically I am trying to figure out a super simple and clean way with html and css to have user avatars sit directly to the left of a comment on an article.

I am trying out float left on an image which works but then block elements seem to still go behind it even though text doesn't?

Any idea why?
See here for example: http://www.prxa.info/articles/rochard.1579#comments

The second comments quote box goes behind avatar but the text does not?

The images are just using this:

```
style="float: left; padding-right: 10px; clear: right;"
```

Tried with and without the clear - no difference.

Comment: Could you please provide us with some code? I see no issues on the webpage in Chrome 23...

Comment: I see the issue in chrome as well, the grey box for the quote goes under the avatar (it's supposed to have rounded corners you can clearly see it being cut off by the avatar.

Comment: I see, but the issue is probably in the image itself; the image might not be transparent, meaning the white of the image is blocking off the quote box.

Comment: Its due to the opaque background of the image. You must have scaled the image. Sometimes the image loses the transparency due to that too. try using the original image. Try changing the height and width of the image using Firebug, you'll understand what's happening!

Answer (score 0):

add these rules

```
.qoute {
   float: left;
   width: 80%;
}
```

and put the rest of the comment in a div and clear the DIV for putting it in new Line

Comment: Not as simple as "put the rest of the comment in a div" the quote is in the full comment text and sometimes there will be multiple ones. Adding float then makes all the text align to the right of it.